# Wine is extremely slow, how do I find out why?

Tags: macports, wine

Recently I updated Wine (among other things) via `port selfupdate` from version 1.2 to version 1.4. After that it takes roughly a minute to start up, even simple things such as `wine cmd` or `winecfg`. CPU usage also spikes to about 140%.

I've tried **completely** removing and re-installing MacPorts (yes, I removed `~/.wine`) and it's still as slow.

How do I get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 2012-03-20 I [updated fontconfig to 2.9.0_0](https://trac.macports.org/changeset/90994); fontconfig is used by wine and other ports to find fonts. Unfortunately there [was a problem](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33769) where fontconfig did not create its cache files correctly, causing it to try to recreate them each time you use a program that uses fontconfig; this could take a minute or more, depending on your disk speed and how many fonts you have installed, since it's indexing all your fonts.

I [updated fontconfig to 2.9.0_1](https://trac.macports.org/changeset/91265) on 2012-03-27 with a patch to fix this so the usual "sudo port selfupdate" and "sudo port upgrade outdated" commands should fix this.